# If $u\in L^1(\mathbb T)$ why $u\in \mathcal S'(\mathbb R^n)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $u\in L^1(\mathbb T)$ where $\mathbb T=\mathbb R^n/\mathbb Z^n$. Why $u\in \mathcal S'(\mathbb R^n)$ ? i.e. $$\left<u,\varphi \right>=\int_{\mathbb R^n}u\varphi ,\quad \varphi \in \mathcal S(\mathbb R^n),$$
where $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ is the space of Schwartz function. Is there a constant $C$ s.t. $$\left|\int_{\mathbb R^n}u\varphi \right|\leq C\rho_{j}(\varphi ),$$
where $$\rho_j=\max_{|\alpha |\leq j}\sup_{x\in \mathbb R}(1+|x|)^j|\partial ^\alpha f(x)| \ \ ?$$

I don't see how to find one.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the periodicity of $u$ you have
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{\mathbb R^n}u\varphi\,dx\right|
&\le\,\int_{\mathbb R^n}|u||\varphi|\,dx = \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z^n}\int_{\mathbb T}|u||\varphi(x+k)|\,dx\\
&= \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z^n}\int_{\mathbb T}|u||\varphi(x+k)|(1+|x+k|)^{2n}\cdot\frac{1}{(1+|x+k|)^{2n}}\,dx\\
&\le p_{2n}(\varphi)\|u\|_{L^1}\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z^n}\sup_{x\in\mathbb T}\frac{1}{(1+|x+k|)^{2n}}\\
&\le 2^np_{2n}(\varphi)\|u\|_{L^1}\sum_{k\in\mathbb N^n}\sup_{x\in\mathbb T}\frac{1}{(1+|x+k|)^{2n}}\\
&\le 2^np_{2n}(\varphi)\|u\|_{L^1}\sum_{k\in\mathbb N^n}\frac{1}{(1+|k|)^{2n}}.
\end{align*}
The last series converges: By means of AM-GM we have
$$
1+|k| = 1+\sqrt{\sum_1^nk_j^2}\ge\sqrt{1+\sum_1^nk_j^2}\ge\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}\sqrt{\sum_1^n(1+k_j)^2}\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\prod_1^n(1+k_j)^{1/n}.
$$
That is,
$$
(1+|k|)^{2n}\,\ge\,\frac{1}{2^n}\prod_1^n(1+k_j)^{2}.
$$
This gives
$$
\sum_{k\in\mathbb N^n}\frac{1}{(1+|k|)^{2n}}\,\le\,2^n\sum_{k_1=0}^\infty\cdots\sum_{k_n=0}^\infty\frac 1{(1+k_1)^2}\cdots\frac 1{(1+k_n)^2} = 2^n\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac 1{(1+k)^2}\right)^n,
$$
which is a finite number.

Comment: Thank you. That looks great, but can I really extend $u$ by $0$ ?

Comment: @reuns Ohh. I interpreted it differently. But I guess it's true what you say.

Comment: @amsmath The OP is looking at the distribution with $u$ periodic, not $u$ supported on the unit interval so you need to look at $C=\sup_x |(1+|x|^{n+1}) \varphi(x)|$ giving that on $m+[0,1]^n$ then $|\varphi(x)| \le C |m|^{-n-1}$

Comment: @reuns Thanks. I took $2n$ instead of $n+1$ to make it nicer.